# iOS horizontal listview

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios

Listview:

I need to implement a listview that is horizontal instead of vertical.

Any example of this?  Is it even possible?

I've try a scrollview, but it doesn't seems to be possible to dequeue cell.  So it's very long to generate.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use a UIScrollView with paging enabled. You'll have to roll your own queueing/dequeuing view implementation though. At most you should only need 3 views in your content view at a time. One to show the current item and the items to the left and the right.

Comment: Check out the [PhotoScroller sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

try this component: https://github.com/Kastet/APCarouselView